# Add ng-if to an image in html

Tags: html, ionic-framework, ionic3, angular-ng-if

So, I have two images on a html page in my ionic project, and I want the second image to show up when the first one is clicked.
Therefore i added a `onClick` to my image like:

```
<img  src="path"
    alt="foo" 
    style="foo;
    width:foo;
    left:30%;top:30%" 
    class = "foo"
    onclick="ng-model='bar'" >
```

And the second image

```
<img  src="path" 
    *ngIf="bar">
```

But it is not working that way. Is it the wrong way? I tried it that way to avoid additional javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this as follows:

```
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150/222222" (click)="hiddenImage.style.display='inline'"/>
<img #hiddenImage style="display: none" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150/888888"/>
```

But it may still be a better idea to do it differently depending on what your exact use case is.

Using *ngIf you would probably still need a variable that holds the value of whether the image should be shown or not in your template:

```
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150/222222" (click)="showImage=true"/>
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150/888888" *ngIf="showImage"/>
```

In your Component you should declare:

```
showImage: boolean = false;
```